# Running shell scripts in a Jenkins DSL mavenJob

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm writing a Jenkins (version 2.6) DSL that will allow me to check out and build a Maven project, run a shell script and deploy it to Artifactory.

```
mavenJob("test-build") {
  multiscm {
    ...
  }
  steps {
    shell ("bash build-scripts/script.sh")
  }
  goals("clean install")
  configure{ project ->
    project/publishers << 'org.jfrog.hudson.ArtifactoryRedeployPublisher' {
    details {
      artifactoryUrl('<url>')
      artifactoryName('<name>')
      repositoryKey('libs-release-local')
      snapshotsRepositoryKey('libs-snapshot-local')
    }
    deployBuildInfo(true)
    deployArtifacts(true)
    evenIfUnstable(false)
  }
  publishers {
    archiveJunit('target/*/.xml')
    publishBuilder {
      discardOldBuilds(7,10)
    }
  }
}
```

The job only works if I remove the `steps{}` block as `steps` aren't permitted in a `mavenJob`. I've tried using a `freeStyleJob`, but `ArtifactoryRedeployPublisher` doesn't work.

What do I have to do to run my shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want shell script to be run ahead of maven goal, you can use this

```
preBuildSteps {
// Runs a shell script.
shell(String command) 
}
```

Or if you want the shell script run after the maven goal, you can use this one

```
mavenJob('example-1') {
postBuildSteps {
    shell("echo 'run after Maven'")
}
}
```

For detail, you can check the job dsl api viewer
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.MavenJob.postBuildSteps

It is very easy and handy tool.

Br,

Tim